# Why does componentDidMount not execute when I navigate to initial route from other screen?

Tags: javascript, navigation, react-native, android-lifecycle

I'm using react-navigation for my mobile app and I have 2 routes- Home and Favoriti, where Home is initial route. Both of those components have componentDidMount. Whenever I navigate to Favoriti from Home, Favoriti component mounts, but when I navigate back to Home, its componentDidMount doesn't execute. It only executes the first time I open the app, but I need it to mount every time I navigate to it.

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import  Home  from './views/Home';
import Favoriti from './views/Favoriti';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({

    FavoritiRT: Favoriti,
    HomeRT: Home
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "HomeRT"
  }
);

const MyRoutes = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default MyRoutes;
```

There is no error showing, it's just that componentDidMount of initial route doesn't execute every time I navigate to it, but with other routes it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"componentDidMount" does not run again because the "Home" component has already been created and will continue to exist as long as it is in the stack. That instance of the Home component will be reused and the user will continue where they left off when they go back to that Home component. To run componentDidMount again you need to start a new instance of the Home component.

Instead of using the back button. Create a button and in the onPress prop navigate to a new instance of Home using the push method.

```
<Button
  title="Home"
  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('Home')}
/>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html#going-back

**Edit:**

While this will get your app running for now; sfratini makes a good point and his answer will be better for you if you end up working for a company/client or publish your own app. Adding a listener would be ideal for all the reasons he said.

Answer (score 3):

Raymond answer should work and the explanation is the same. ComponentDidMount only runs once and it has no need to run again as you Have Home in your stack.

I would recommend adding a listener on the componentWillReceiveProps which should be firing as well when the Home screen loads again, and you can see if you need to refresh or reload the screen.

But of course, it depends on your use case. If you keep pushing the Home screen on the stack, the only downsize is that once the user reaches Home, usually the back button should mean "leaving the app" and if you push it to the stack and you press back, you will just go back one screen. To be that is bad UX, but if taht works for you, fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried adding a listener, but componentWillReceiveProps wouldn't fire when I come back to Home screen. Using replace instead of navigate worked for me.